# Сокращение времени на получение отклика requests

Tags: python, requests

Собственно. Есть список ссылок, если интернет доступен - ссылки отправляются в функцию, которая проводит свои манихации и вставляет их в лэйбл. Однако попадаются заблокированные ссылки, которые без прокси не откроешь. К ним нужно отдельное поведение. Я попытался реализовать это через `requests.get`, тем более что он у меня в этой функции используется. И с конструкцией `try-except` всё работает как надо, однако он довольно долго пытается к ней пробиться. Как можно сократить это время?

p.s вставил joyreactor потому что этот сайт в моей стране недоступен. Какую бы вставить универсальную - не знаю.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from threading import Thread
import socket
import requests

def network_connection_check(link):
    try:
        socket.gethostbyaddr(link)
    except socket.gaierror:
        return False
    return True

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        links = ['http://www.joyreactor.cc', 'https://www.youtube.com/',
                 'https://www.google.com/']

        for i in links:
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            self.vbox.addWidget(label)
            thread = Thread(target=self.html_foo, args=(i, label))

            if network_connection_check('www.google.com') is True:
                thread.start()


    def html_foo(self, link, label):
        try:
            page = requests.get(link)
            label.setText(str(page))

        except:
            label.setText(link + 'error')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно изменить время получения отклика с помощью параметра `timeout`. 
Информация из [документации requests](https://pythonru.com/biblioteki/kratkoe-rukovodstvo-po-biblioteke-python-requests)

```
def html_foo(self, link, label):
    try:
        page = requests.get(link, timeout=4)
        label.setText(str(page))

    except:
        label.setText(link + 'error')
```

Comment: Верно, надо использовать опцию timeout. Только для проверки доступности следует не полностью контент грузить, а всего лишь проверить response status code (https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes)

Comment: А таким образом можно проверять доступность интернета вместо функции, которую использую я, проверяя status code у гугл, например? И будет ли это так же эффективно или там есть свои недостатки?

Comment: Почему же? Вполне можете вначале проверять доступность, например, google.com таким же образом и, если все работает, то сразу же дальше свой ресурс через проверенный прокси...